# Google Cloud Auth vs. Firebase Auth

Tags: firebase, authentication, google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-storage

I'm currently creating a small web app where a user is able to upload a picture to firebase.

Looking into everything I found many tutorials on the sign in using google oAuth and firebase auth. I'm unsure of what to choose and why? Are these different products?

My guts tell me to look into firebase auth since I want to upload to it as well. Or are these working hand and hand and do I need both to get my idea from paper to screen?

Answer (score 0):

You can [authenticate your users in Firebase using Google](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/google-signin). Why would you do that? Simply to be able to use [Firebase products](https://firebase.google.com/products-build), and secure your apps. So in case you need to upload an image to [Firebase Cloud Storage](https://firebase.google.com/products/storage), then you'll be able to write [security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security). Then you can, for example, let a user read only his profile picture and nothing more.

Comment: Hey lechnerio. Can I help you with other information?